# Alerts and or Validation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to create an alert for when Cell B is Blank and text is being typed into Cell C, I also need then, for Cell C to be able to have free text typed in once there are figures in Cell B.

any help greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Hi Kelly, What have you tried so far? With Excel formulas alone I don't you would be abble to lock/unlock cells based on the precense of data in another cell.

Comment: Hello, I worked on this a little more and I actually used an IF statement in Data validation =IF(ISBLANK(B2),"req number required",(ISTEXT(C2))) and added an Error alert. Seems to work ok and allow me to enter Text once B has been populated, but only Text, I can't input just numbers.... but this works for ma as I need to only enter text in the cells. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use data validation to prevent entering any values into cell C while cell B is empty.

Go to Data group in the ribbon - data validation

- for "allow" select `custom`
- unselect "ignore blank"
- for formula enter:
  `=OR(AND(A2="",B2=""),A2<>"")`

Now trying to enter anything to B2 will give an error if A2 is empty. Note that there is no way to prevent typing in that cell, message will appear only when typing is finished (Enter pressed or trying to move to another cell).

Also note that message will appear only when you try to type to B2 while A2 is empty, if you delete content of A2 while B2 contains anything that will not trigger it, it would require another rule.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel's data validation features to display an alert message before the user enters text in column C. This will display an alert message, but it will not prevent the user from entering text.

Steps:

1. Select cells in column C you want to display the alert.
2. On the Data ribbon, choose `Data Validation` > `Data Validation...`.
3. Choose the `Input Message tab` in the dialog. Here you can type a warning message that will display as tool-tip text when the user selects one the cells in column C.

   [image]
4. Click OK. You will now see the warning message whenever one of the cells is selected.

   [image]

This may not be as robust a solution as you wanted, but it may work well enough and is very easy to set up.